# Make misaligned twocolumn documents even

Tags: sectioning, two-column, alignment, parskip

For a `twocolumn` document using `memoir` I am preparing, I find that when modifying `\parskip` for greater paragraph separation and making use of `\section` to divide the text into different parts, this yields, in the end, (a) uneven, misaligned columns, such that **lines of text on the left column do not sit at the same height as those on the right**; and (b) **the box of text**, when it takes up the whole page, **is often jagged at the bottom** as opposed to straight (see the attached image and the MWE below).

Special cases aside, I would prefer if the box were perfectly rectangular, when the text continues on the next page; and that its lines on one column be on par with those on the other, which seems to me to be the true culprit behind the jaggedness at the bottom. **What can be done to fix this?**

```
\documentclass[9pt, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}%This and the used of \section misaligns the two columns. How to fix this?

\begin{document}

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-2]

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-1]

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: Misaligned columns and jagged bottom.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get warned

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

In the column with no sections you have specified impossible consraints. No flexible glue and the total glue and line heights is not `\textheight`

Making the glue flexible makes the consraints achievable. (Alhough it is somewhat unusual to have both `\parindent` and `\parskip` non zero)

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 1ex}%This and the used of \section misaligns the two columns. How to fix this?

\begin{document}

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-2]

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-1]

\section{Sample section}

\lipsum[0-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In other words, to fix this I must relax the constraints I have imposed?

Comment: @JoelDacasa or set constraints that are not inconsistent. `twocolumn` defaults to `\flushbottom` ie the last baseline is at the bottom, but in the second column you have a vertical list of text lines and fixed parskip glue so there is no possible way to adjust the position of any baseline. This is user-error not a problem with the class.

Comment: Fair enough, I will look into what you say further. Thank you very much, Mr. Carlisle.

Comment: @JoelDacasa if you want a fixed \parskip set it to \baselineskip so that a paragraph does not throw you off grid.

Comment: Thank you once again. Just tried it and it has been a big help!