# Two-column document: text is not vertically aligned

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column

I am writing an article using this template https://github.com/acl-org/acl-style-files, and there is an ugly misalignment which I couldn't manage to fix:

[image]

The above shows the last two lines of a page. The last line of the left column is pushed to the first line of the right column instead of staying on the left, leaving an ugly space. My question is how to fix this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update:** Minimal working example:

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[review]{EACL2023}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\lipsum \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The above requires `eacl2023.sty`, which can be downloaded from [this page](https://2023.eacl.org/calls/styles/). The result:

[image]

Comment: is there room for another line on the left? Your  image suggests not, and you have provided no code. (note the baselines on the left is lower so another line on the left would be lower than the line on the right, whch might be too low to fit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Apparently there is no space left on the left, but then I don't see why that is the case. On the left column I have no line break, that is, the entire column is part of a single paragraph, which means that it should span the whole column height without leaving any space, but it does not...

Comment: please don't use external links: add a small complete example that shows the problem in a code block in the question,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added an MWE in the form of a zip file, please have a look. Unfortunately it was not possible to provide such example using code blocks only, as I'm using an external template. Thanks.

Comment: This output leads one to believe that it sets `\raggedbottom`.  That is probably done for a reason, but you can try setting `\flushbottom`, preferably after `\begin{document}` (I'm avoiding downloading your zip file to check).  That should result in both columns ending at the same place at the bottom, but possibly leaving some rather obvious empty areas elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I have checked the template file and found no `\raggedbottom` though. I have updated the question with an code-block MWE. Could you please have a look? Thank you in advance.

Comment: cc @DavidCarlisle as well for the update

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually `\flushbottom` is already set in the template... I found a similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640914/make-misaligned-twocolumn-documents-even, which was answered by David. I guess the author of the template has set wrong values, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: @f10w -- yes, that's the usual situation that will yield the result you're getting.  Resetting `\parskip` to add a small bit of stretchability is the recommended approach.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I've tried adding `\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 1ex}` before `\begin{document}` in the above MWE, but the issue still remains :(

Comment: I do not get the output you show, [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD1YW.png) latex does scream that it hs impossible constraints: `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active`

Comment: Aha!  In the page that @DavidCarlisle shows, there is *no* paragraph break, not a single one.  In such a case, the only alternative is to add a tiny bit of stretch to the baseline skip, or (for the example page) some shrink after the section heading.  This is an extreme and unusual situation, but it happens, so must be taken into consideration.  And in order to make a correct analysis of a problem, it's necessary to know all the conditions.  This situation wasn't taken into consideration in the class design, an unfortunate, but common, failure.

Comment: the package does not make \textheight-\topskip a multiple of \baselineskip so every column of just text can not be set without underful box warnings, spaces around section headings are not given enough stretch to compensat a full baselineskip and so on, I think if you need to use the package for a conferece submission, just accept it for what it is (@barbarabeeton)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. In the output you show, there is a small misalignment at the bottom of the page though. The second page should be worse, similar to the second image in my question. Would you mind giving some advice on how to fix the template file? I'm going to let the organizer know about this issue, and will point them to your comment above as a hint, hopefully they'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: @f10w no I had a quick look, you'd have to rewrite the entire thing, aligning the columns just wasn't a requirement in that file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Your comments were helpful.